# Minted with frame and bgcolor

Tags: minted

I have a problem with minted. I have created a new minted environment like so:

```
\definecolor{dhscodebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted[dhscode]{hs}{tabsize=4, fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=lines, framesep=\fboxsep, bgcolor=dhscodebg, rulecolor=\color{gray!40}}
```

If I use it like so:

```
\begin{dhscode}
foo :: Double -> Int
\end{dhscode}
```

The result is:

[image]

You will notice the space between the frame and where the background ends. Is there a way to get rid of this space?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This affects all your `minted` environments. One work around is to set `\fboxsep` to `0pt` in the definition of `minted@colorbg` as follows.

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\z@}
\def\minted@bgcol{#1}
\noindent
\begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
{\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\colorbox{\minted@bgcol}{\usebox{\minted@bgbox}}}
\makeatother
```

Here is a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). (You should construct one in succeeding posts for speedier replies. A lot of answerers do not like to work from scratch.)

```
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\z@}
\def\minted@bgcol{#1}
\noindent
\begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
{\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\colorbox{\minted@bgcol}{\usebox{\minted@bgbox}}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{dhscodebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted[dhscode]{hs}{tabsize=4, fontsize=\footnotesize, frame=lines, framesep=5\fboxrule,framerule=1pt,
bgcolor=dhscodebg, rulecolor=\color{gray!40}}

\begin{document}
\begin{dhscode}
foo :: Double -> Int
\end{dhscode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can not use this since I use minted in other ways as well, but it's better than nothing.